Testing for pattern in positions or the lack thereof in long linear molecules
About a month ago, I asked a question about finding a suitable statistical test
to establish whether a particular kind of event at various positions on a long
linear molecule (mtDNA), could be identified as spaced regularly apart (ie
multiples of 3 if all such results may occur at a wobble base assuming one knows
the reading frame in the absence of introns), or occurring in clusters (most within short distances of one another with longer intervals elsewhere along the molecule), or essentially randomly scattered over the entire length of the molecule with no discernable
pattern to intervals between the positions at which the event is observed to occur.
Unfortunately, my repeated efforts to search for my question to see if any
additional comments or answers were offered suggests that it may no longer be listed
among the questions (surprisingly my account shows I have not asked any
questions on Cross Validate), which leads me to post this question again.
Hopefully my repost is at least somewhat better posed than before.
My question elicited two interesting responses but no specific answers, with one
bringing to my attention the interesting phenomenon of CpG islands, which
apparently reflect clustering at positions close to one another. Although both useful
comments suggested my question was ill-posed, the comment regarding CpG islands
suggested to me that some kind of statistical test may have been performed to
confirm that the pattern with respect to position for the event of interest was clustered, rather than regularly or randomly spaced along the length of the DNA. If so, what test(s) would be appropriate to demonstrate this statistically?
In my initial post, I asked if perhaps a Kolomogorov-Smirnov runs test against
expected cummulative distributions, might be appropriate to distinguish among
these three different kinds of outcomes. The Chi-Square test appears to have been
used in the identification of CpG islands, but it is unclear to me precisely how
this test would be performed in my situation. In my situation, I am not interested
in the identify of the base-pair combinations per se, but rather whether the
positions at which compatible transitions are present, as elucidated by
character compatibility analysis, are patterned (regular spaced or clustered) or
random, without any discernable positional pattern along the entire length of the molecule.
The situation here may be somewhat more complicated in that a random pattern might still potentially reveal that in translation, such positions could correspond to possibly amino-acid substitutions at "non-random" places on a highly folded protein (ie more/less inside/outside, within/between motifs, etc.). Nonetheless, the analogy between CpG sites and compatible sites, with respect to their relative position seemingly still holds.
